# jQuery code that searches for a div and sets an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was working on a piece of code that looked for a div that had the css style `clear: both` after the page loaded and then added css `display: none`.

This is a sample of my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).load(function () { 
      if( $("div").css('clear').toLowerCase() == 'both') { 
        $(this).css("display", "none"); 
        }); 
      });
    </script>
    <title>Check</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div>This is visible</div>
     <div style="text-align: center; font-size: smaller; clear: both;">This is not visible.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, this code does not seem to work out...I'm kind of new to jQuery. Can someone point out my error?

Comment: isn't it easier to give a class to all those needed elements? And then `$(".new_class").hide();`?

Comment: Imagine that I cannot change the div...Then I cannot add a class to the div.

Comment: oh. then azim's answer is the one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css()` method like following.

```js
$('div').css('display', function () {
    if ($(this).css('clear') == 'both')
        return 'none'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is visible</div>
<div style="text-align: center; font-size: smaller; clear: both;">This is not visible.</div>
```

**Update:** Use `$(document).ready` instead of `$(document).load`.

Comment: Use `$(document).ready` instead of `$(document).load`. See this https://jsfiddle.net/1nrh7vch/ @I.Am.A.Guy

Comment: Yes, works after I changed load to ready. Please add this also to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use to search all the divs with a specific style:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).find('div').each(function() {
      if($(this).css('clear').toLowerCase() === 'both') {
          $(this).css('display', 'none');
       }
    })
  })
```

In the above code, `.each()` will search all the div in the document and then we check is css property `clear`

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/q3maznyt/